# How to disable design view and lay out view option for users in ms access

Tags: ms-access-2010

[image]

users must not be able to make changes in form. In the snapshot bottom right corner, design view and layout view options is available. How to hide them or disable for users.
My frontend consists of login form and main form.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a 12-year-old and unsupported version of MS Access?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lock Design View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596501/how-to-lock-design-view)

Comment: @Dai: I'd say license costs, plus it doesn't introduce [breaking bugs](https://www.devhut.net/category/ms-access/ms-access-bugs/) every few months like Access 365 does. I wish I could use Access 2010 in all my projects. </rant>

Comment: @Dai Don't know, this is my company's desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer.
on top left corner click on files>options> current database> uncheck Display status bar option, Enable layout view, Enable design changes for datasheet view.